# Why when rotating a matrix you multiply it by the rotation and the transposed of the rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, matrix-equations, rotations

I have the matrix:

```
    |x 0 0|
A = |0 y 0|
    |0 0 z|
```

which represents axis of a cube for example. Now I want to rotate my cube along along y, so I have the rotation matrix along y:

```
     |cos(a)   0   sin(a)|
Ry = |0        1        0|
     |-sin(a)  0   cos(a)|
```

I had thought I'd only need to multiply them as:

```
A' = A*Ry
```

And this would give me the new rotated `x` and `z` values.

However, I have found some documentation saying that it should actually be:

```
A' = Ry*A*RyT
```

where `RyT` is the transpose of Ry. Anyone can tell me if this is accurate as I can't find more info on it and if so why do I need to do this?
I still have the outside axis x, y and z at the same position, however the cuboid is rotated, if that makes sense.

Comment: Your rotation matrix is $$Ry = \begin{pmatrix}
        cos(a) &  0 &  sin(a)\cr
    0  &      1  &     0\cr
         -sin(a) & 0  & cos(a)
\end{pmatrix}$$ instead.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your model ? (what is your "cube" and its representation ? Some reference about the context.

Comment: Yep, sorry, didn't see it!

Comment: In fact $$\begin{pmatrix}
        u &  0 &  0\cr
    0  &      v  &     0\cr
         0 & 0  & w
\end{pmatrix}$$ is just a dilation of the vectors (I prefer not to use $x,y,z$)

Comment: Erm, not sure, what you mean, I just have a cube and as it is x, y and z of the cube lie along the Cartesian plan. So I want to rotate x and z by an angle 'a' along the y axis